# Silent tor process crashes

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Tor always exhibited an array of what I'll call "silent crash" behavior, in which TorBrowser becomes unable to access specific or often any webpages.  Afaik, these happen on all platforms, but certainly they're ubiquitous on Linux & Mac.  I've noticed silent crashes become much worse over the last six months or so, with invariably almost every TorBrowser session experiencing "silent crashes" eventually.

At least 4+ years ago, you could *always* solve these by `killall -HUP tor`, or by identifying & killing the specific `tor` process if this killed other processes.  At some point however, TorBrowser started crashing whenever you kill its `tor` process, which is clearly a bug in TorBrowser

Afaik, all you could do now is (a) wait 10 minutes in hopes `tor` comes back once its current circuits expire, or (b) save all tabs and close TorBrowser or refresh identity.

Are there work arounds for TorBrowser crashing when you kill its `tor` process?

Ideally of course, TorBrowser should add a button to "refresh only tor process but do not clear browser state", or at least add integration tests that TorBrowser does not crash when users run `killall -HUP tor`.